# Reverse Geocoding Code

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I've been working on putting together the Javavscript code for Reverse Geocoding in Google maps. I thought I'd solved all the issues I had, but I'm still having problems.

When I embed the Javascript code within the HTML file it works without any problems. However if I try and run the javascript (with some alterations), as a separate file, the map loads upon opening my form, but when I enter the Lat and Lng co-ordinates and press the relevant button to Reverse Geocode, all that happens is that the map is refreshed.

I've attached the HTML file with the JS code embed and then the separate JS code file to make a comparison.

HTML file with embedded Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Reverse Geocoding</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function codeLatLng() {

    var lat = document.getElementById('Latitude').value;
    var lng = document.getElementById('Longitude').value;

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng, 
              map: map
          }); 
        var address= (results[1].formatted_address);
        document.getElementById('Address').value= results[1].formatted_address;
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);


          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div>
  <input name="Latitude" type="text" id="Latitude" size="16" maxlength="10" />
  <input name="Longitude" type="text" id="Longitude" size="16" maxlength="10" />
  <input name="Address" type="text" id="Address" size="55" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Reverse Geocode" onClick="codeLatLng()">
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 90%; top:60px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code

```
(function ReverseGeocode() {

    //This is declaring the Global variables

    var geocoder, map, marker;

    //This is declaring the 'Geocoder' variable
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    window.onload = function() {

    //This is creating the map with the desired options 
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            }
            };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
        var form = document.getElementById('SearchForLocationForm');

        //This is getting the 'Latitude' and 'Longtiude' co-ordinates from the associated text boxes on the HTML form
        var lat = document.getElementById('Latitude').value;
        var lng = document.getElementById('Longitude').value;

        //This is putting the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' variables together to make the 'latlng' variable
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        // This is making the Geocode request
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {

        // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding    
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        //This is placing the marker at the returned address    
            if (results[1]) {
          // Creating a new marker and adding it to the map
            map.setZoom(16); 
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, draggable:true
          });
        }

        var address= (results[1].formatted_address);

        //This is placing the returned address in the 'Address' field on the HTML form  
        document.getElementById('Address').value= results[1].formatted_address;
                }
            }
);
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the short version of Khepri's (thank you!) Code

```
function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    // This is making the Geocode request
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert(status);
        }
        // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
        }
    });
}
```

this is also needed, do not forget in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much man for extracting only the part which is needed the most! worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I took what you had an modified it to something that functions for me...

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body onload="ReverseGeocode.Init()">
    <div>
        <input name="Latitude" type="text" id="Latitude" size="16" maxlength="10" />
        <input name="Longitude" type="text" id="Longitude" size="16" maxlength="10" />
        <input name="Address" type="text" id="Address" size="55" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Reverse Geocode" onclick="ReverseGeocode.ReverseCode()">
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 90%; top: 60px; border: 1px solid black;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This would be my test.js code below

```
var ReverseGeocode = function () {

    //This is declaring the Global variables

    var geocoder, map, marker;

    //This is declaring the 'Geocoder' variable
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function GeoCode(latlng) {

        // This is making the Geocode request
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {

            if(status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                alert(status);
            }
            // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding    
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                //This is placing the marker at the returned address    
                if (results[0]) {
                    // Creating a new marker and adding it to the map
                    map.setZoom(16);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map, draggable: true
                    });
                    marker.setPosition(latlng);
                    map.panTo(latlng);
                }

                var address = (results[0].formatted_address);

                //This is placing the returned address in the 'Address' field on the HTML form  
                document.getElementById('Address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
        });

    }

    return {

        Init: function () {

            //This is putting the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' variables 
                            //together to make the 'latlng' variable
            //var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885, -73.997383);

            //This is creating the map with the desired options 
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

            GeoCode(latlng);
        },

        ReverseCode: function () {

            //This is getting the 'Latitude' and 'Longtiude' co-ordinates from the associated text boxes on the HTML form
            var lat = document.getElementById('Latitude').value;
            var lng = document.getElementById('Longitude').value;

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            GeoCode(latlng);

        }
    };

} ();             // the parens here cause the anonymous function to execute and return
```

I basically replaced the window.onload handler you were using and set up the "object" with an init event that sets up the map initially. Then I just exposed a function that grabs the user entered lat/lng and called in to our geocode wrapper.

Should work with little modification (outside of copious amounts of error handling that I skipped :-p ) for you.

Comment: Hi, sincere thanks for your reply and the code. I've tried it and unfortunately I can't get anyhting to happen when I click the 'Reverse Geocode' button. Any ideas please? UPDATE - I've managed to get this working, it was just a missing semicolon. Many thanks for your help. Kind regards

Comment: I've uploaded the example above for you. http://www.guilette.net/Example.zip Just extract and run and it will work. (FYI, this is my personal domain. If you're not comfortable grabbing the file from there, let me know and I'll put the file wherever you prefer)  EDIT: Glad you got it working!